# How to fix input getting cut off by output

Tags: java, user-input, irc

So, I'm trying to create a function (If not pretty) IRC client using no libraries, written in Java. I've gotten almost everything working, the only problem is that I'm currently getting user input using System.in. And if someone else in the channel sends a message while I'm in the middle of typing, it cuts off what I currently have, and I need to guess where I am in the string. I want to know if there's a way to separate user input from the output of the program, so that this doesn't happen. This is the code in question:

```
new Thread(() -> {
            while(connected[0]) {
                String output = sc.nextLine();
                if(!output.startsWith("~") && !output.startsWith("/")) {
                    try {
                        writeToSocket("PRIVMSG " + focused[0] + " " + output);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(output.substring(1).toLowerCase().startsWith("quit")) {
                    String[] split = output.substring(5).split(" ");
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                        if(i == 0) {
                            sb.append(split[i]);
                        }
                        sb.append(" ").append(split[i]);
                    }
                    try {
                        writeToSocket("QUIT " + sb.toString());
                        connected[0] = false;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else if(output.substring(1).toLowerCase().startsWith("focus")) {
                    String get = output.substring(7);
                    if(!channels.contains(get)) {
                        print("Not connected to channel");
                    }else {
                        try {
                            writeToSocket("PART " + focused[0]);
                            writeToSocket("JOIN " + get);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        focused[0] = get;
                    }
                }else if(output.substring(1).toLowerCase().startsWith("join")) {
                    String get = output.substring(6);
                    channels.add(get);
                }

                if(output.startsWith("/") && output.substring(1).toLowerCase().startsWith("msg")) {
                    String[] split = output.substring(5).split(" ");
                    String username = split[0];
                    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
                        if(i == 1) {
                            msg.append(split[i]);
                            continue;
                        }
                        msg.append(" ").append(split[i]);
                    }
                    try {
                        writeToSocket("PRIVMSG " + username + " " + msg.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: I'd say it is a terminal's problem (an OS tool), which is outside the java's jurisdiction, unless you want it to make into a GUI application.